# Automatically add order to the right customer in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to learn Django by making a database for a fictional dog kennel.

One thing I don't understand is how I can automatically add a animal to a customer. What I mean by this is that when I go to my customer page (dynamic) I made a button to a form called AnimalsForm. In this form I have to select a customer again. I was wondering how I could make the form so that it automatically takes the customer from which page I entered the form.

**Models.py**

```
        from django.db import models
    import datetime
    
    # Create your models here.
    
    class Customer(models.Model):
    # Info klant
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        adres = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        residence = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True) 
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True) 
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    # Info referentie
        ref_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        ref_residence = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        ref_phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True) 
    # Datum aangemaakt
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    
    
    class Doctors(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        residence = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    
    
    class Animals(models.Model):
        SPECIES = (
                 ('Hond', 'Hond'),
                 ('Kat', 'Kat'),
                 ('konijn', 'Konijn'),
                 ('Cavia', 'Cavia'),
                 ('Vogel', 'Vogel'),
                )
    
        SIZE = (
                 ('Klein', 'Klein'),
                 ('Middel', 'Middel'),
                 ('Groot', 'Groot'),
                 ('Extra groot', 'Extra groot'),
                )
    
        SEX = (
                 ('Man', 'Man'),
                 ('Vrouw', 'Vrouw'),
                )
    
        CASTRATED = (
                 ('Ja', 'Ja'),
                 ('Nee', 'Nee'),
                )
    
        BARKS = (
                 ('Niet', 'Niet'),
                 ('Normaal', 'Normaal'),
                 ('Veel', 'Veel'),
                )
    
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
        species = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=SPECIES)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        race = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        size = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=SIZE)
        weight = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=SEX)
        castrated = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CASTRATED)
        date_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
        color = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        characteristics = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        doctors = models.ForeignKey(Doctors, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
        date_kennelhoest = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        date_anderevacinaties = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        chipnumber = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        date_chipnumber = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        food_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        food_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        food_morning = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        food_afternoon = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        food_evening = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        behavior_dogs = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        behavior_people = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        behavior_kennel = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        behavior_medicine = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    
    class Options(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    
    
    class Visits(models.Model):
    #Datums
        date_brought = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, null=True)
        date_leave = models.DateField(null=True)
    #Options; halen/brengen ; samen in één hok ; afgerekend ; bevestiging verstuurd
        options = models.ManyToManyField(Options)
        note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    #Other realtions
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
        animals = models.ForeignKey(Animals, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)


**Animalform.py**
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**Button for creating a new animal**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_animal' %}">Nieuw dier toevoegen</a>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'

class VisitsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visits
        fields = '__all__'

class AnimalsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animals
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('visits/', views.visits, name="visits"),
    path('animals/', views.animals, name="animals"),
    path('doctors/', views.doctors, name="doctors"),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer, name="customer"),

    path('create_customer/', views.createCustomer, name="create_customer"),
    path('update_customer/<str:pk>/', views.updateCustomer, name="update_customer"),
    path('delete_customer/<str:pk>/', views.deleteCustomer, name="delete_customer"),
    path('create_visit/', views.createVisit, name="create_visit"),
    path('create_animal/', views.createAnimal, name="create_animal"),
    
    path('update_animal/<str:pk>/', views.updateAnimal, name="update_animal"),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import *
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    visits = Visits.objects.all()

    vandaag_brengen = visits.filter(date_brought=datetime.date.today()).count()
    vandaag_halen = visits.filter(date_leave=datetime.date.today()).count()

    context = {'visits':visits, 'vandaag_brengen':vandaag_brengen, 'vandaag_halen':vandaag_halen}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

def visits(request):
    visits = Visits.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/visits.html', {'visits':visits})

def animals(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/animals.html')

def doctors(request):
    doctors = Doctors.objects.all()

    context = {'doctors':doctors}
    return render(request, 'accounts/doctors.html', context)

def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)

    animals = customer.animals_set.all()
    visits = customer.visits_set.all()
    context = {'customer':customer, 'visits':visits, 'animals':animals}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)

def createCustomer(request):

    form = CustomerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_form.html', context)


def updateCustomer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/customer/%s' % pk )

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer_form.html', context)



def deleteCustomer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer.delete()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'item':customer}
    return render(request, 'accounts/delete.html', context)




def createVisit(request):

    form = VisitsForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VisitsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/visits_form.html', context)



def createAnimal(request):

    form = AnimalsForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnimalsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/animal_form.html', context)


def updateAnimal(request, pk):
    animal = Animals.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = AnimalsForm(instance=animal)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnimalsForm(request.POST, instance=animal)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/animal_form.html', context)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: post you code here, not code images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What did you try? And what errors did you get?

Comment: @zero Thanks for the feedback. I have added the code.

Comment: @rocha I tried making a normal form. This doesn't give any errors, but when you add a pet when on the dynamic page of a customer you have to choose the customer again in the form.